# How can i change style components in dexoExchange?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, blockchain, styled-components, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to fork the Dexo exchange interface from GitHub and add my own styling to it. The problem is I haven't found a way to change the header nav bg color and footer bg as well as 80% of the rest of the react ts components.

I've followed multiple tutorials and have been reading up on typescript's styled-component documentation but I haven't been able to find any examples or documentation that is similar to uikit.

The core theme provider code that is used is: pancake-uikit - Here is where all my confusion lies and where I haven't been able to find any documentation for this type of theme setup.

If you visit the uikit repository , you can see all of the core styled-components related code.
Actually I'm less familiar with typescript and styled components.

Here is the picture of dexoexchange:
[image]

Here is a picture of of what I've been able to change:
[image]

The github repo for my code is here:  https://github.com/sohaib57/dexoExchange.git

I know this is a very open-ended question but I'm on week 2 of trying to get this to work and any help would be greatly appreciated.